# Find all possible combination in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have excel data like this

```
X    Y

a    1
b    2 
c    3
```

I want to do all possible combination in Column X, and generating sum from column Y

```
a+b    3
a+c    4
a+b+c  6
b+c    5
```

Comment: Have you looked on here? I am sure this type of question has been asked and answered... What have you attempted so far?

Comment: For how many X do you plan to do this? Because this will be calculateable by VBA until about 8 Xes and then it will exceed time and memory and becomes impossible because of too many permutations that need to be calculated. See [How To Generate Or List All Possible Permutations In Excel?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3657-excel-generate-all-permutations.html)

Comment: Actually i don't have much knowledge of excel. @solar mike andreas

Comment: @AnkitSagar Please, can you answer my question? Because if you plan 8 or more X this is impossible. If you plan less then 8 start with the link in my comment.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ it is more than 8, is there anything around?

Comment: Hm just realized that the order might not be important and therefore more than 8 would be possible but still this will exceed fast if it is much more than 8 How many X do you have?

Comment: Hm just realized that the order might not be important and therefore more than 8 would be possible but still this will exceed fast if it is much more than 8 How many X do you have? • Another question: 3X results in a `a+b+c` combination will 4X result in `a+b+c+d`? Or is the maximum 3 combinations?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ  I have 20 X.  my combination depends upon number of X.

Comment: @AnkitSagar Are you sure that this is what you want? Because for 20 it will result in `1,048,555` combinations (no order important, no repetitions) that's a lot and will probably already exceed the limits. This is already one full column of results. Everything below `823543` is known that it can be calculated in VBA. You should re-think if you really need `1,048,555` combinations and if that is the correct approach. What is the purpose of all that?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ sorry, actually i want to do it for 20 X, with each X having maximum of 3 combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example produces the output in the immediate window. Adjust it to your output needs.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Combine()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim iRow As Long, jRow As Long, kRow As Long
    For iRow = 2 To LastRow
        For jRow = iRow + 1 To LastRow

            'output 2-combos
            Debug.Print ws.Cells(iRow, "A").Value & "+" & ws.Cells(jRow, "A").Value, ws.Cells(iRow, "B").Value + ws.Cells(jRow, "B").Value

            For kRow = jRow + 1 To LastRow
                'output 3-combos
                Debug.Print ws.Cells(iRow, "A").Value & "+" & ws.Cells(jRow, "A").Value & "+" & ws.Cells(kRow, "A").Value, ws.Cells(iRow, "B").Value + ws.Cells(jRow, "B").Value + ws.Cells(kRow, "B").Value
            Next kRow
        Next jRow
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

So this …
[image]

will output …

```
a+b            3 
a+b+c          6 
a+b+d          7 
a+c            4 
a+c+d          8 
a+d            5 
b+c            5 
b+c+d          9 
b+d            6 
c+d            7
```